# MVC4 base(connectionStringOrName)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I have searched for many pages but still don't know the function for base(connectionStringOrName). Can anyone help answer? Thanks

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? what's the goal for `base(connectionStringOrName)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base(...)` calls the constructor in the base DbContext class that has those arguments.

- In this case  `public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) { ... }`
- [EF `DbContext.cs` Source Code](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs)

An example of calling a base constructor:

```
public class A { 
    // note there is no paramaterless constructor
    public A(string message) {
        Console.WriteLine("In A: " + message); 
    }
}

public class B : A { 
    public B() : base("from class B") {
        Console.WriteLine("B's Constructor");
    }
}

public class C : A { 
    public C() : base("from class C") {}
}

var b = new B();
var c = new C();

// Output
//   In A: from class B
//   B's Constructor
///  In A: from class C
```

Comment: Thanks. When should I use the base("DefaultConnection") & DbContext in my model?